# Bibtex authors appearing as dashed lines in references when using bookdown and pandoc

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bookdown, bibliography, pandoc-citeproc

I'm generating a reference section using Rmarkdown, bookdown and pandoc. I have a reference section with 6 entries. One of the entries does not have the author list, and instead appears as:

```
———. 2004. “Multimodel Inference.” Sociological Methods & Research 33 (2). SAGE Publications: 261–304. doi:10.1177/0049124104268644.
```

The bibtex entry of this looks as follows:

```
@article{burnham2004,
    author = {Burnham, Kenneth P. and Anderson, David R.},
    day = {01},
    doi = {10.1177/0049124104268644},
    issn = {0049-1241},
    journal = {Sociological Methods \& Research},
    keywords = {mdb-article-2017-06},
    month = nov,
    number = {2},
    pages = {261--304},
    posted-at = {2017-06-05 22:18:23},
    priority = {2},
    publisher = {SAGE Publications},
    title = {Multimodel Inference},
    url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0049124104268644},
    volume = {33},
    year = {2004}
}
```

As far as I can tell this bibtex entry is correct, what is causing the author list not to be shown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dashed lines means that the author(s) of this entry is the same as the previous entry ([example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/references.html)), hence omitted. That is the default behavior of pandoc and pandoc-citeproc when the output format is HTML. If you do not want this behavior, you need to provide your own citation style (via `csl` in YAML or the `--csl` argument). See http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citations for more information.

Comment: Very useful to know, thank you. I was not familiar with this convention. Where is this normally used? I work in biology and I don't think this is used in our field.

Comment: Honestly it was also the first time that I had seen this style when I started to use Pandoc. I don't know which fields or journals actually use this style.

Answer (score 2):

Yihui Xie is correct that this is a style-specific setting. You can either switch to a CSL style that doesn't use this type of author substitution, or you can edit your current CSL 1.0.1 style and delete the `subsequent-author-substitute` and (optional) `subsequent-author-substitute-rule` attributes from the `<bibliography/>` element. (see also http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/1.0.1/specification.html#reference-grouping, which also explains in more detail how this type of substitution works)